# How to solve Error: tailwindcss/no-contradicting-classname?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, linter

The classes have the following properties `bg-[url('/images/img.webp')] bg-right` I need to align the background picture to the right edge, and I get an error when checking with a linter

```
Error: Classnames bg-[url('/images/img.webp')], bg-right are conflicting!  tailwindcss/no-contradicting-classname
```

Is there any way to bypass or correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

Using this strategy to your property classnames.

```js
const styles = [
  "bg-[url('/images/img.webp')]",
  "bg-right",
].join(" ");
```

Then put in your react `className` property.

```js
<div className={styles}>Hello World</div>
```

**Full Code**

```js
const styles = [
  "bg-[url('/images/img.webp')]",
  "bg-right",
].join(" ");

const SomeComponent = () => {
  return <div className={styles}>Hello World</div>
}
```